# Bringing up Orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I thought of a scenario where the orderer and peers are at different host machines. Now what will happen if the orderer is crashed somehow and all the orderer data has been deleted. Is it possible to start another orderer and get its data back from the blocks created by the peers and resume the normal functioning of fabric ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario which you described is the reason why Hyperledger Fabric team are working to bring about a Simplified Byzantine Fault-Tolerent Orderer. The SBFT is being developed, but there are no fixed time-line for release yet.
[You can see here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/blockchain.html#what-is-hyperledger-fabric) under the 'consensus' headline that BFT mechanism is under the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

In production environment, it is always wise to use more than one orderer. Using a single orderer is having a single point of failure. This is mentioned in the documentation also. And as far as i know from the documentation the Orderer keeps its data in memory, so if that fails you loose out on orderer data.